# PINE - Close trade at the end of the bar, Close after x minutes

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a difficulty on closing trades on the end of the candle. I want that the strategy opens a trade according to signal and close it at the end of the bar. I've studied nearly all posts but could not come to a conclusion. I was checking it like " open time + x minutes " or "candle open to candle close" . I'm not a programmer but have the insight of what is what (its not like chinese to me) but I cant come along with the trade close. I came along to strategy.close.all" but again can not make it work :( Any help is appreciated.

```
ReversalLong = low < low[1] and close > high[1] and open < close[1]
ReversalShort = high > high[1] and close < low[1] and open > open[1]


alertEntryMessageBUY = "buy tradesymbol=NAS100 lot=2"
alertEntryMessageSELL = "sell tradesymbol=NAS100 lot=2"

if ReversalLong
    strategy.entry('BUY', strategy.long, alert_message=alertEntryMessageBUY)

if ReversalShort
    strategy.entry('SELL', strategy.short, alert_message=alertEntryMessageSELL)
```

Tried defining open price and close after xx minutes
Tried defining the opening candle and close it on the next one ( index[1] - index[0]

Comment: Are you trying to close a trade at the end of a bar or x minutes after the entry? Where is your code related to that?

Comment: Trying to close at rhe end of the candle. I also gone with the idea like closing in xx minutes, tried to approach the same result (like I go in on 4 hr candle open and close after 4 hours-> close of the candle). As I told, Im not a programmer and any code I placed just makes no sense :(

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't share your code that is not working.

Comment: I'm trying this like getting the entry time :
firstEntryTime = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(0)
'strategy.closeall("ID", when = 
firstEntryTime + 10 --> 10 pretends to be 10 minutes here
@virtuvius